# Is it possible to only restore one record from a backup into a production database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, sql-server-2019

I have been trying to use SQL Server 2019 import and export data's query function to be able to restore one record from a table into the production database to fix its quantity. Unfortunately whenever I try to an error shows up.

```
- Validating (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202048: Data Flow Task 1: Attempting insertion into the row version column "DBTimeStamp". Cannot insert into a row version column.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Item" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I already tried to set the ones that showed a warning to ignore.

What do I do?

Comment: If it's just one record, I would just insert it by hand and move on.

Comment: Backup/restore has nothing to do with import/export. Your import statement is incorrect and should not be attempting to insert into that column (it's generated automatically).

Answer (score 1):

> Attempting insertion into the row version column "DBTimeStamp". Cannot insert into a row version column.

Whatever method you're using, you need to exclude the DBTimeStamp column (because you cannot explicitly set a value for a column with datatype rowversion).

If you're using the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard", you can accomplish this by choosing "Edit Mappings" for the destination table in question and selecting "ignore" in the drop down menu for that column.